Provider Verifier using wrong providerBaseUrl
I am using pactflow for the first time and I am working on provider verification script but somehow the verifier keeps hitting a different base url, (My consumer test works fine and it even publishes the pact to pactflow) any help would be greatly appreciated
I have ensure that the server is up, and hitting the endpoint from postman and with curl, it works fine (I have also tried using the actual endpoint and verifying the pact from provider)
Provider Verification
import { Verifier } from '@pact-foundation/pact';
import path from 'path';

const providerName = 'Provider';
const providerBaseUrl = 'http://localhost:8081'; // Adjust this as needed

describe('Pact Verification', () => {
    const opts = {
        provider:"Povider",
        verboseIsImplied:true,
        publishVerificationResult: true, 
        providerVersion: '1.1.12', 
        providerVersionTags: ['none'], 
        pactUrls: [path.resolve(process.cwd(), './pacts/consumer-provider.json')], 
         providerBaseUrl:providerBaseUrl }

    it('should verify the provider against the Pact files', async () => {
        const verifier = new Verifier(opts);
        try {
          await verifier.verifyProvider();
          console.log('Provider verification successful');
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Provider verification failed:', error);
          throw error; 
        }
      });
    });

Pact
  "consumer": {
    "name": "Consumer"
  },
  "interactions": [
    {
      "description": "a request to provider",
      "request": {
        "body": "SampleString",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "method": "POST",
        "path": "/myEndpoint"
       
      },
      "response": {
        "body": {
         "templateDetails":{
            "templateID": 0
          },
          "id": 101,
          "name": "Sample Name"
        },
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "status": 200
      }
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "pact-js": {
      "version": "13.1.4"
    },
    "pactRust": {
      "ffi": "0.4.22",
      "models": "1.2.3"
    },
    "pactSpecification": {
      "version": "2.0.0"
    }
  },
  "provider": {
    "name": "Provider"
  }
}```

This is what I see in the logs 
2024-10-25T23:30:49.791291Z  INFO ThreadId(04) pact_verifier::provider_client: Sending request to provider at http://127.0.0.1:54435/
2024-10-25T23:30:49.791619Z  INFO ThreadId(04) pact_verifier::provider_client: Sending request HTTP Request ( method: POST, path: /myEndpoint2024-10-25T23:30:49.794616Z  INFO ThreadId(04) pact_verifier::provider_client: Received response: HTTP Response ( status: 400, headers: Some({"x-content-type-options": ["nosniff"], "content-security-policy": ["default-src 'none'"], "content-type": ["text/html; charset=utf-8"], "date": ["Fri, 25 Oct 2024 23:30:49 GMT"], "keep-alive": ["timeout=5"], "connection": ["keep-alive"], "content-length": ["1272"], "x-powered-by": ["Express"]}), body: Present(1272 bytes, text/html;charset=utf-8) )


I tried hitting the endpoint from postman and it provides a valid response 

